# ROR How to limit user actions

Tags: ruby, database

I'm just forcing with this kind of problem. Im making my first app, and want to make sth like this:

When admin loggin, he can make everything (CRUD), but when user login he can only see what is in primary db, and if sth he like he add this to his basket. He can only operate on his basket, I mean add and delete. Im trying to use for this CanCan + Devise, am I at got road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the actions you just have to ensure that the user is able to perform this actions with a before_filter in the actions:

```
before_action :check_admin, only: [:admin_actions_array]
before_action :check_user, only: [:create, :delete]

def check_user
  return false unless current_user
end

def check_admin
  return true if current_user.admin
end
```

This will do the trick without using can-can.